# Reduce Flutter carousel slider padding

Tags: flutter, widget, carousel

I'm using carousel_slider flutter plugin. I want to reduce the space between 'items' widgets. Here's my code:

```
CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(
            enableInfiniteScroll: false,
            initialPage: 0,
            height: screenHeight * 0.35,
            enlargeCenterPage: true,
            viewportFraction: 0.85
          ),
          items: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              color: Colors.blue,
            )
          ],
        )
```

and this is what I'm getting:

[image: output]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want your items to fill all screen width, you should set viewportFraction to 1 :

```
viewportFraction: 1,
```

If you want to keep a lower ratio and remove space between items, the default `CarouselOptions()` seems to achieve that.

It seems that your parameter that differs from defaults is `enlargeCenterPage: true`, you might want to keep it false.

I recommend to have a look at the examples [here](https://github.com/serenader2014/flutter_carousel_slider/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart).

Comment: Thank you for your response. You're right, it was the enlargeCenterPage that was creating a padding around the children widgets. What I wanted was to increase the size of the center widget without any horizontal distance between them. I did it by setting enlargeCenterPage to true and enlargeStrategy to CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height.

Answer (score -1):

You also Try to change Change This Value Like this

````
                 autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                 aspectRatio: 18/9,
                 viewportFraction: 0.9,
                 enlargeCenterPage: true,
                 enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                 enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.zoom,
                 padEnds: true,

```[enter image description here][1]

[enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/86xdE.jpg
````